# What is the Z transform of the discrete PI control model？

Tags: control-system, pid-controller, matlab, simulink

I have a discreate PI controller implemented in stm32 MCU, it has the following form:
$$
 PI=K_p\cdot[r(t_i)-y(t_i)] + (K_I)\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{i}[r(t_n)-y(t_n)]\cdot\Delta t
$$
where

- \$r(t_i)\$ is the target (or input) value,
- \$y(t_i)\$ is the output value and
- \$\Delta t\$ is the sampling time.

I use the \$\sum\$ function to implement the integral function while  the error term is \$[r(t_i)-y(t_i)]\$.`

I need to simulate this PI controller in MATHLAB Simulink.

Besides, I have found another form of the PI controller: it doesn't has the sum equation, and but has the following structure:
$$
PI=K_p\cdot[r(t_i)-y(t_i)]+ (K_I)[r(t_i)-y(t_i)]\cdot\Delta t
$$
For the integral term of this PI controller, the \$Z\$-transform is
$$
K_I(z)=e(z)\cdot T\cdot\frac{ z}{z-1}.
$$
**My question is**: how to write the \$Z\$-transform equation of my PI controller?  if I use the `sum equation` to sum the error term,  how should I represent the second term correctly in the \$Z\$-transform domain?